# MySQL - Check for multiple same values in one row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL-table with the following structure for songs in a chartlist.

ID - Title - Artist - Releaseyear - 1999 - 2000 - 2001 - 2002 - 2003 - ..etc.. - 2013.

The columns '1999', '2000' etc are the positions of the song in the chart of that year.

Now I want to check which songs are on the same place in at least three years.

I've found queries for finding duplicates on multiple rows, but not yet for this case.

Comment: please show your code ?

Comment: Or at least create sql fiddle, and output you want

Comment: What a sucky schema. In 2 days will you have to rewrite all your queries to know about the 2014 column?

Comment: @Barmar: No, it is an annual chart. I can simply add the 2014 position in december 2014. :)

Comment: That still means you have to update all your queries every year. Data that varies should be in column values, not the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `UNION` to convert the columns to rows, then you can find duplicate rows.

```
SELECT ID, place, GROUP_CONCAT(year ORDER BY year) years
FROM ( -- Pivot the table to get all the years and places in the same column
    SELECT ID, "2001" AS year, `2001` AS place
    UNION
    SELECT ID, "2002" AS year, `2001` AS place
    UNION
    ...
    UNION
    SELECT ID, "2013" AS year, `2013` AS place
    ) AS byYear
GROUP BY ID, place
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```